# Object going out of scope and destructor called causing the pointer following that object's address to have unreadable memory on each attribute

Tags: c++

So I have a vector of pointers to `Movie` objects in a class called `Movies` and the `Movies` class has a member method `add()` which you pass in the following arguments: `std::string name, std::string rating, size_t watched_times`. Then that `add()` method constructs a `Movie` object with all the arguments passed in, then I `push_back()` the address of that `Movie` object, the problem is when the code block is finished that `Movie` object will be destructed and so all the attributes will be "unreadable memory" or "random".

I just can't figure out how to go around this, any ideas on how to try going about this would be greatly appreciated.

**`Movie.h`**:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Movie {

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string rating;
    size_t times_watched;
    bool init{false};

public:

    // private attribute getters
    std::string return_name();
    std::string return_rating();
    size_t return_times_watched();
    bool return_init();

    // Methods
    void increment();

    Movie(std::string name_val, std::string rating_val, size_t times_watched_val); // Constructor

};
```

**`Movie.cpp`**:

```
#include "Movie.h"


// private attribute getters
std::string Movie::return_name() {

    return name;

}

std::string Movie::return_rating() {

    return rating;

}

size_t Movie::return_times_watched() {

    return times_watched;

}

bool Movie::return_init() {

    return init;

}

// Methods
void Movie::increment() {

    ++times_watched;

}

Movie::Movie(std::string name_val, std::string rating_val, size_t times_watched_val) : name{name_val}, rating{rating_val}, times_watched{times_watched_val}, init{true} {}
```

**`Movies.h`:**

```
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Movies {

private:
    std::vector<Movie*> movies;

public:

    bool add(std::string name, std::string rating, size_t times_watched);
    bool increment(std::string name);

    void display();

};
```

**`Movies.cpp`**:

```
#include "Movies.h"

bool Movies::add(std::string name, std::string rating, size_t times_watched) {

    for (size_t i{}; i < movies.size(); ++i) {

        if (movies.at(i)->return_init() && movies.at(i)->return_name() == name) {

            return false;

        }

    }

    Movie to_add{name, rating, times_watched};
    movies.push_back(&to_add); // Causing bug
    return true; // End of loop means no name matching name was found to the new movie being added

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're describing.

Comment: ***Then that add() method constructs a Movie object with all the arguments passed in, then I push_back() the address of that Movie object*** Make sure you are not using `&` to get a pointer to a Movie which is some local variable. Storing the address of an item that will go out of scope is undefined behavior if the pointer still exists after the object is destructed.

Comment: Yes the bug is definitely here: `movies.push_back(&to_add);` the object `to_add` no longer exists when `Movies::add()` finishes however your movies vector points to the address of the non-existant object. I question your use of pointers. If movies was `std::vector<Movie>` you could just `movies.push_back(to_add);` and the code would work and your would not have to worry about memory leaks also.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code to the question. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Problem: Using a pointer to a local variable is bad after the variable is out of scope. Solution: Don't save pointers to local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, the issue is with

```
    Movie to_add{name, rating, times_watched};
    movies.push_back(&to_add);
```

After these lines, the `Movie` object goes out of scope, causing the `to_add` variable to be destroyed. The pointer you pushed onto the `movies` variable is no longer valid. Using it is then undefined behaviour.

There are a few possibilities to fix this. If you insist on storing points in the `vector`, then you can do

```
    Movie *to_add = new Movie{name, rating, times_watched};
    movies.push_back(to_add);
```

Since this object is now dynamically allocated, it will not be automatically destroyed. You will be responsible for freeing the memory though, presumably in the destructor of the `Movies` class. A better solution would be to change the `vector` to store `Movie` objects, as opposed to pointers, i.e. `std::vector<Movie>`. Then, you can simply push objects onto the vector.

```
    Movie to_add{name, rating, times_watched};
    movies.push_back(to_add);
```

or

```
    movies.push_back(Movie{name, rating, times_watched});
```

As an aside, when passing objects into function, it's generally a good idea to pass them by constant reference, in order to prevent copies being made. Example:

```
bool Movies::add(std::string name, std::string rating, size_t times_watched)
```

Would become

```
bool Movies::add(const std::string &name, const std::string &rating, size_t times_watched)
```